# UISearchDisplayController inside UIPopOverController - searchResultsTableView not displaying properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

So I have a tableview inside a `UIPopOverController` and I attached a UISearchBar to the header of the tableview and I have the `UISearchDisplayController` displaying the correct results. However, I can't get the results to display within the `UIPopoverController` window. It's displaying behind the popover view into the `DetailView` covering half the screen (`SplitViewController` for iPad). How do I bring the results/tableview into the popover view? I tried adding the `searchTableView` to the popover view, but it just covers up the original tableview.

Here is the code of setting this up:

```
 //Initialize Popover Controller
UIView *ccPopoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIViewController* popoverTableContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

self.ccTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.ccTableView.dataSource = self;
self.ccTableView.delegate = self;
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 44.0)];
self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 38);
self.ccTableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

ccPopoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


//Here is where I tried adding the searchResultsTableView as a subview.
//[ccPopoverView addSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView];
[ccPopoverView addSubview:self.ccTableView];


popoverTableContent.view = ccPopoverView;

self.popoverTableController.delegate = self;
self.popoverTableController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverTableContent];

[self.popoverTableController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 440) animated:NO];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue instead of adding `self` when I initialized the search bar, I needed to put in the popovercontroller as the initialization.